# liquibase modal dialog on non-local db

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase to create some tables in Oracle and I am using oracle6 driver.

Now when I point my liquibase to a database that is not on my local machine there is a modal dialog comming up saying something like "You are connecting to a remote database. Do you want that?".

Does someone know how to turn off this dialog?
Liquibase with this thing is kind of not usable on Jenkins or a remote machine without X11 turned on.

Comment: I found an answer here http://blog.nutpan.com/2012/03/liquibase-maven-plugin-issue-with-non.html

The solution is to add the following to your liquibase-plugin part in your pom.xml

<promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>

Comment: Documented here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_tag.html

Comment: um .... no, thats not the documentation for this config property ... at all

Answer (score 22):

I found an answer here http://blog.nutpan.com/2012/03/liquibase-maven-plugin-issue-with-non.html The solution is to add the following to your liquibase-plugin part in your pom.xml

```
<promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
```